# sum with start and end dates of the month

Tags: powerbi, dax

How to add a certain column in POWER BI, with the date condition that the user inserts in a selection filter in which the date 01 of each month with year is available, where it takes the reference date and returns the first and last day of the month selected in the calculation of the sum.

ADDCOLUMNS(VALUES(cooperados[data_base]), "total_peso", [sum_pesos])

Comment: What's your ultimate goal? Are you trying to return something like a total per month? Save yourself a lot of hassle and create a Calendar table with columns like MonthYear, MonthNumber, Year, etc, and then you can just group by that by dragging the column you need into your matrix.

Comment: yes the total per month, but the reference date is another column and take this referenced date, pull the beginning and month of that date and apply the filter of that period in the sum.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to get the first and last day of each month.
you can use the following functions for that

- [STARTOFMONTH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/startofmonth-function-dax)
- [ENDOFMONTH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/endofmonth-function-dax)

if you create those columns in your date table, then you will e able to get you calculation with somthing similar to this :

```
Calculate (
    Sum(MyColumnToSum),
    DATESBETWEEN(DateTable,GetStartOfMonth,GetEndOfMonth)
)
```

Comment: Right, even more would have to take the filter that the user selected and play on that start and end date of the month

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd do some research on Date Dimensions/Calendar tables, because a good Calendar table in your data warehouse/star schema will make most of the questions like these super easy to answer.